# XGBoost installation failing

Tags: python, ubuntu, xgboost

I'm trying to install XGBoost on my AWS Ubuntu machine.

I followed the instructions and installed GCC and cmake. However, when I write

```
pip install xgboost
```

I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
        'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
    XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
    List of candidates:
    /tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
    /tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
    /tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sorzhu8y/xgboost/
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to python documentation:

> This module makes available standard errno system symbols. The value
>   of each symbol is the corresponding integer value. The names and
>   descriptions are borrowed from linux/include/errno.h, which should be
>   pretty all-inclusive.

So Error code 1 is defined in errno.h and means Operation not permitted.

Your setuptools do not appear to be installed. 
So, try to upgrade python tools

> pip install --upgrade setuptools

If it's already up to date, check that the module ez_setup is not missing. If it is, then

> pip install ez_setup

Then try again

> pip install unroll

If it's still not working, maybe pip didn't install/upgrade setup_tools properly so you might want to try

> easy_install -U setuptools

and again

> pip install unroll

for me was resolved after upgrading pip
let us know about you..

Answer (score 0):

There are instruction in the site: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

First:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
make -j4
```

Then:

```
cd python-package
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: for me still says "XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?"